# How to Copy a link in a website via ajax call?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-scraping, copy

I would like to copy the first link in another website without loading the website.

I can copy text with the below code, what if i want to copy the first link or in a website without loading the website how can i achieve it? If i can achieve it without ajax call call please also post your method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in a different window, to see the effect.</p>

<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No matter what you are loading the request for the site just not performing script-action.  So request the page and its contents look for first link; more than do-able.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK Kindly clarify please.